# how assign JSON data to global variable?

Tags: json

why variable undefined and how put json data to global variable?

```js
var responce;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status === 200) {
        responce = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(responce.trainers);
    }
}

xhttp.open("GET", "trainers.json", true);
xhttp.send();

console.log(responce); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The response variable will get a value when the `onreadystatechange` callback is fired... Until then... the variable is undefined...

U need to access it in the callback
I.e. put the `console.log(response)` in the callback...

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status === 200) { 
        responce = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(responce); // Value will be defined at this point
        console.log(responce.trainers); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Depending on the result of the if statement, it may still not get a value.

Comment: Possibly... but my answer is based on where the OP indicated with the comment...

Comment: I want to export parsed json object. does it possible to export it to use as global variable?